# Kibana server is not ready yet even started

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

i have 1 master node (master), and 1 data node(node-1). 
Im using centos7 as os.

### master:9200

```
[root@localhost kibana]# curl localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "master",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "P4QlwvuRRGSmlT77RroSjA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "aa751e09be0a5072e8570670309b1f12348f023b",
    "build_date" : "2020-02-29T00:15:25.529771Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

### node-1:9200

```
[root@dev ~]# curl localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "P4QlwvuRRGSmlT77RroSjA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "aa751e09be0a5072e8570670309b1f12348f023b",
    "build_date" : "2020-02-29T00:15:25.529771Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

### both node can see each other

```
[root@localhost kibana]# curl master:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 27,
  "active_shards" : 27,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 27,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```

kibana installed on master node.
systemctl status kibana.
updated log on kibana

```
[root@localhost kibana]# systemctl status kibana -l
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-06-04 09:49:15 WIB; 28min ago
 Main PID: 61223 (node)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─61223 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

Jun 04 09:49:44 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:44Z","tags":["warning","plugins","security","config"],"pid":61223,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in kibana.yml"}
Jun 04 09:49:44 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:44Z","tags":["warning","plugins","security","config"],"pid":61223,"message":"Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended."}
Jun 04 09:49:44 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:44Z","tags":["warning","plugins","actions","actions"],"pid":61223,"message":"APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml."}
Jun 04 09:49:44 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:44Z","tags":["warning","plugins","alerting","plugins","alerting"],"pid":61223,"message":"APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml."}
Jun 04 09:49:44 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:44Z","tags":["info","plugins","monitoring","monitoring"],"pid":61223,"message":"config sourced from: production cluster"}
Jun 04 09:49:44 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:44Z","tags":["warning","plugins","monitoring","monitoring"],"pid":61223,"message":"X-Pack Monitoring Cluster Alerts will not be available: undefined"}
Jun 04 09:49:45 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:45Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":61223,"message":"Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations..."}
Jun 04 09:49:45 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:45Z","tags":["info","plugins","watcher"],"pid":61223,"message":"Your basic license does not support watcher. Please upgrade your license."}
Jun 04 09:49:45 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:45Z","tags":["info","plugins","monitoring","monitoring","kibana-monitoring"],"pid":61223,"message":"Starting monitoring stats collection"}
Jun 04 09:49:46 localhost.localdomain kibana[61223]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-04T02:49:46Z","tags":["error","savedobjects-service"],"pid":61223,"message":"This version of Kibana (v7.7.0) is incompatible with the following Elasticsearch nodes in your cluster: v7.6.1 @ 10.64.2.246:9200 (10.64.2.246), v7.6.1 @ 10.64.2.99:9200 (10.64.2.99)"}
```

how do we know compatible version between kibana and elastic? i've checked [matrix](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix) it didnt show what kibana version support what elastic version
Any kind of respond will be appreciated so much. thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is on the last Kibana log line.

> This version of Kibana (v7.7.0) is incompatible with the following Elasticsearch nodes in your cluster: v7.6.1

You're running ES 7.6.1 and Kibana 7.7.0, that won't work. Both need to be on the same version.

Comment: hi Mr Val. Thank you so much for your respond. I will try to upgrade the rest soon. But i have some question. Is it a must to have it same version? do i have to upgrade beat,logstash,elasticsearch to the same version? or that terms only working on elasticsearch and kibana?

Comment: You can run a [higher ES minor/patch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/setup.html) version than Kibana but not the other way around. Regarding Beats and Logstash, it is a little more permissive, but you should strive to always use the same versions or you risk to encounter incompatibilities.

Comment: I've upgraded my elastic on both node. then restart kibana, and start both node's elastic. Works like a charm. Thank you so much

Comment: This isn't always the issue -- this error comes up even if your Kibana and ES versions match, as might happen if you also see the error `Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes` (which can appear while ES is online/passing health checks). Unfortunately, ES+Kibana do not include enough useful context to figure out what is going wrong (like exactly what URL(s) it's trying to hit).